# Strange behaviour of PB

Tags: oracle, powerbuilder

It's very hard to add this code without revealing sensitive data or even obfuscate it, so I explain problem as best as I can.

There is a user objects, let's call them **uo_object** and **uo_caller**.

**uo_object** has 2 events:
*ue_refresh_1* and *ue_refresh_2*

object **uo_caller** calls events from **uo_object** like:

`iuo_obj.event ue_refresh1`.

PROBLEM:
When i full-build application, and run it, line `iuo_obj.event ue_refresh1` 
calls not event **ue_refresh1** but **ue_refresh2**(?!?!?!?).
But when i open powerbuilder and add a space, new-line any where in this uo_caller,line `iuo_obj.event ue_refresh1` calls ue_refresh1.
Of course when i build application after adding space or new-line, this behaviour is repeating.

Does anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Sounds like you aren't actually running the newly-built version, but some old version?

Comment: Yes, application is old, but we are on powerbuilder 2017 r2/r3 and it is happening on both versions. Application is also very big, and problem appears only in this one object

Answer (score 2):

Consider this a shot in the dark.

Export this object **and its ancestors** and look for:

Multiple events assigned to the same underlying event id, e.g.

```
uo_obj
   ue_refresh_1 pbm_custom01

uo_ancestor
   ue_refresh_2 pbm_custom01
```

Events assigned to conflicting underlying events, e.g.

```
uo_obj
   ue_refresh_1 pbm_custom01

uo_ancestor
   ue_refresh_1 pbm_custom02
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have an idea why but something you could try is to put some additional code around your "iuo_obj.event ue_refresh1" statement.  Something like:

```
IF 1 = 1 THEN
   iuo_obj.event ue_refresh1
END IF
```

Then get latest version on all the objects (you do use source control right?) and then do a full build.